# How to call a parameterized method (using dataprovider) from a different class?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, dataprovider

I am facing an issue wherein I have created a parameterized method that uses dataprovider. Both DataProvider and method and created in same class. Now, I want to call this method from another class but it requires parameters to be passed which I cannot since they are being read from dataProvider.

I have tried declaring the dataProvider in different class too but that doesn't work. Please suggest some workaround for it.

**NOTE: I have a restriction that I cannot use TestNG.xml to implement this scenario.**

Please find the code below:

**DataProvider:**

```
@DataProvider(name = "TestSuite")
    public Object[][] dataSheetTraverser() {
        String SheetName = "ProgLang";
        datatable = new Xls_Reader(TestDataSheetPath_ProgLang);
        int rowcount = datatable.getRowCount(SheetName);
        Object result[][] = new Object[rowcount - 1][3];
        for (int i = 2; i < rowcount + 1; i++) {
            result[i - 2][0] = SheetName;
            result[i - 2][1] = i;
            result[i - 2][2] = datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "caseType", i);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Test Method:**

```
@Test(dataProvider="TestSuite_ProgLang",priority =2)
    public void TC_Verify_EditProgLang(String SheetName,int i, String caseType)
    {

        String test1= datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "Skills", i);
        String test2= datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "Version", i);
        String test3= datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "LastUsed", i);
        String test4= datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "ExperienceYr", i);
        String ExperienceMn = datatable.getCellData(SheetName, "ExperienceMn", i);

        proglang.FillForm_ProgLang(Skills, Version, LastUsed, ExperienceYr, ExperienceMn);

    }
```

I want to call the above function **TC_Verify_EditProgLang** from another class. Please suggest.

Comment: wait .... you want to call a (Unit ? ) Test from another class?

Comment: @Stultuske not unit test. I want to perform the same action from another class as well.

Comment: ok, so what type of test is this?

Comment: that method is also a @test method inside a testNG class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dataProviderClass` attribute for calling from other class
 in @Test  and The Provider method Must be `static`  :

```
public class StaticProvider {
      @DataProvider(name = "create")
      public static Object[][] createData() {
        return new Object[][] {
          new Object[] { new Integer(42) }
        };
      }
    }
    //different Class
    public class MyTest {
      @Test(dataProvider = "create", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
      public void test(Integer n) {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

please check the Documentation :[dataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: the problem is that I have to keep DataProvider and test method inside same class and call the test method from another class (i.e., I have to call **MyTest** class from somewhere else)

Comment: you need create Object for MyTest Class in Other Class call method .in your scenario you need pass the data to method.new MyTest().TC_Verify_EditProgLang(....pass Parameters);